# How to process String operations on GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to preprocess some strings and I think maybe Tensorflow can accelerate this process on GPU.
There are two regex functions that I found which I need for my project.
However, when I try to use them on GPU, it only processes on CPU.

Here is the test code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy

device = tf.config.list_logical_devices(device_type="GPU")[0]

with tf.device(device):
  inp_token = tf.identity(['foliões', 'viagem'])
  pattern_verify = tf.identity(f'.*ões$')
  result = tf.strings.regex_full_match(inp_token, pattern_verify)
  print(inp_token.device)
  print(pattern_verify.device)
  print('tf.strings.regex_full_match on device: ', result.device)

  replace = tf.identity('ão')
  replaced = tf.strings.regex_replace(inp_token, pattern, replace)
  print(replace.device)
  print('Processed data: 'replaced[0].numpy().decode('utf-8'), replaced[1].numpy().decode('utf-8'))
  print('tf.strings.regex_replace on device: ',replaced.device)
```

And here it is the return:

```
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
tf.strings.regex_full_match on device: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Processed data: folião viagem
tf.strings.regex_replace on device: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
```

See that the two regex functions results are on device 'CPU' instead of in the 'GPU', as it is for its inputs.

Comment: Hmm. There's been academic research published indicating that regex matching _can in theory_ be GPU-accelerated, but it's a good distance from having a proof that it's possible to having it actually implemented in any given production-quality framework, especially when that framework is implementing PCRE-style "regexes" instead of true Thompson NFAs.

Comment: (See https://github.com/MadhumithaSridhara/QuickMatch for one implementation).